# What actually happens when two buttons on form are equated?

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose we have two buttons on a form, `button1` and `button2`, and these events are associated with them

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button1");
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button2");
    }
```

if we executed `button1 = button2` using another button, then both of them should refer to the same component as `button1.Equals(button2)` is true, and now for example `button1.Text` is the same as `button2.Text`,

but if i clicked on `button1`, it still shows "button1", and if i executed `button1.Click += button2_Click`, button1 still shows "button1", but `button2` shows "button2" **twice**.

Does `button2` now have two references of it so that the event executed twice? but what about `button1` that actually displayed on form? did i lose its reference? I don't understand what happened and what the equality really do with buttons or form components in general that have events like the BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: You just lost the *reference* to the button1 object.  It continues to live on, stays visible on your UI.  And since its Click event was registered *before* you lost the reference, it knows to keep calling button1_Click.  Writing code like this just isn't very useful.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, it looks clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers are attached to the button objects. `button1` and `button2` are only reference variables that point to that objects (lets call it `obj1` and `obj2`). If you attach the event handlers and then let the variable `button2` point to the object `obj1`, the event handler is still attached to `obj2`.

Answer (score 1):

> if we executed button1 = button2 using another button, then both of them should refer to the same component as button1.Equals(button2) is true

If you assign `button1` to `button2`, it all depends where you do the assignment. If you do the assignment in the click handler of `button1` when `button1` is clicked like this:

```
var clickedButton = (Button)sender;
clickedButton = button2;
```

Then, even though the `sender` is `button1`, and you assign `button2` to it, you are only assigning to a *copy of the reference of button1*. The references are passed by value.

However, if you did this:

```
button1 = button2;
```

and you have no `button1` within the method where you did that, then `button1` will be the same reference as `button2`. It would be the same as below:

```
this.button1 = this.button2;
```

I put together a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/26eGtS) to show all this. I will also copy the code here so it is available. There are comments in the code to provide explanation.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static Form f1 = new Form();
    public static void Main()
    {
        f1.button1.Text = "Button 1";
        f1.button2.Text = "Button 2";
        // The Click method will change the buttons but the change 
        // will only be within the Click method. Not outside.
        f1.button1.Click(f1.button1, EventArgs.Empty);

        // This will still write "Button 1"
        Console.WriteLine(f1.button1.Text);

        // Now if we do the assignment like this
        f1.button1 = f1.button2;
        f1.button1.Click(f1.button1, EventArgs.Empty);

        // this will write "Button 2"
        Console.WriteLine(f1.button1.Text);

        // Now pass as reference
        // We will pass button3 whose text is "Button 3" but it will be assigned
        // to button4, so the output will be "Button 4"
        f1.button3.Text = "Button 3";
        f1.button4.Text = "Button 4";
        button1_Click(ref f1.button3, EventArgs.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(f1.button3.Text);
    }

    public static void button1_Click(ref Button sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sender = f1.button4;
    }
}

public class Form
{
    public Button button1 = new Button();
    public Button button2 = new Button();
    public Button button3 = new Button();
    public Button button4 = new Button();
    public Form()
    {
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        button2.Click += button1_Click;
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedButton = (Button)sender;
        clickedButton = this.button2;
    }
}

public class Button
{
    public EventHandler Click;
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```